# Load empty values from referenced node in Views (Drupal 7)

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, parent-child, cck, entityreference

I have a view displaying nodes of two content types. The nodes all have a cck field made with Entity Reference referencing a "parent" node. If the displayed node in the view has an empty value, the view should display the value in the parent node. Simple as that.

The filters should also be able to filter on the parent's values...

I'm thinking it should be solved with handlers somehow, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding my way through the documentation. Could anybody please help?

I'm working with Drupal 7.14, Views 7.x-3.3 and Entity Reference 7.x-1.0-rc3+2-dev.

-- Mikkel